# Service Bus Receiver subscription close() - abandons message?

Tags: node.js, typescript, azureservicebus

My Service Bus queue receiver uses the `subscribe` function to receive messages from the queue. I save the object returned from the  `subscribe` call that includes a `close()` function. When I call the `close()` function to close the subscription, will the receiver abandon any messages that are still processing, or will it finish processing the current messages?

Answer (score 0):

Calling `close` on the subscription stops actively receiving messages from Service Bus but does not abandon (or otherwise settle) messages that have been emitted to your application for processing.

If your application decides to stop and does not explicitly settle messages that it holds, they will remain locked until the lock duration expires.  At that time, they will be made available for another receiver to read.